# How to prompt Save As dialog on file download

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to prompt a save as dialog when downloading a file, but what I get is, or the file is opening on a browser or it is downloaded without prompting for the save location and save name.

My Controller's code:

```
public FileContentResult Save(string text)
{         
    string contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=outname.txt"); //EDIT
    return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text), contentType, "outname.txt");
}
```

I've tried a different variations of FileResult/ActionResult, application/text etc.

Client code:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
    function submitForm() {
        txt = document.getElementById("textFld");   
        form = document.getElementById("submitForm");   
        input = document.getElementById("messages").outerHTML;   
        txt.value = input;   
        form.submit();
    };
</script>

<table id="messages"> ... </table>

<form action="Home/Save" method="POST" id="submitForm">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="textFld">
</form>

<input type="button" id="submitBtn" onclick="submitForm()">

<script>
    subm = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
    subm.click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer**

You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment` in the response to instruct the browser to save the file.

**New answer**

It looks like this is a known Chrome issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=380652

Comment: I've tried this: Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=out.out"); but it doesn't work...

Comment: Do you actually see that header in the response the browser receives?

Comment: yes: ....
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
...
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=out.out
......

Comment: So it's not using the filename you specified?

Comment: It's do, it save the file with a name specified, but without prompting for a save location and name..

Comment: I may be misinterpreting..."out.out" was in your comment, but "outname.txt" was in your question.

Comment: I tried different combinations... With Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment"); return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text), contentType); I'm getting: Content-Disposition: attachment

Comment: Okay...I misunderstood your question...apologies. I thought you weren't getting the file to download. What browser(s) are you targeting?